# import problem with pythontex

Tags: python, pythontex

I compile the following tex file with pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode and pythontex, but got an error. How can I fix this? I have also tried "from math import comb" but it said there is no comb. Is this a version problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{pycode}
from random import randint
from sympy import *
\end{pycode}
\begin{document}
  \py{binomial(4,2)} is fun\pyc{var=randint(0,100)}
  \py{'ABC'.lower()} is the basics.
  \py{var}
  \pyb{foo=100}
  \pyc{var+=100}
\begin{pycode}
print(r'\begin{center}')
print(r'\textit{A message from Python!}')
print(r'\end{center}')
print(var)
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

```
---  Messages for py:default:default  ----
  Traceback (most recent call last):
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 10:
    File "/py_default_default.py", line 51, in 
      from sympy import *
  ImportError: No module named sympy

-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just for clarification: can you import `sympy` from regular Python? If yes, are you using a Python distribution that sets up its own execution environment, like Anaconda on Windows?

Comment: I personally use sympy with qtconsole, but I have pip installed it inside a terminal. I can use sympy in a terminal too.

Comment: Ok, and do you run pdflatex from the same terminal, or from an editor?

Comment: @Marijn I tried running it from vim with :! command.